# Git: Cannot pull on account of ignored tree

Tags: git

I have a .gitignore that contains the `ignored` folder but when I try to pull I get the error:

```
ubuntu@ip:/some/folder$ sudo -u www-data git pull 
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    ignored/file_A  
    ignored/file_B  
    ignored/file_C 
    ... 
Please move or remove them before you can merge. 
Aborting
```

Why does git bother with stuff I have in .gitignore? Is there a way to go around this WITHOUT deleted the `ignored` folder?

Comment: Did you add those entries to .gitignore AFTER they were already versioned?

Comment: Hm maybe, I'm not sure :)